# Import Excel into SQL Server with ASP.NET MVC in a list so it will easy

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a table where I have fields

```
public class Exceldate
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a SQL Server 2008 table `Exceldate`... and I have an Excel sheet in the sheep there is 2 field ID and Name... I just want to fetch that data by list... simple

There are 10000 rows

My question which is the best approach to import the data from Excel into SQL Server 2008? It has lots of check like duplicates check etc.,

Comment: it's only insert, no update ? Checks are inside the Excel data, or do you have to check between db data and Excel data ?

Comment: So, you're saying there is too much duplication and inconsistency in the Excel data to use SSIS or even an ODBC connection to the Excel sheet? If so, that leaves you with Interop or perhaps a 3rd party solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using Linq to Excel? Pretty simple and straight forward way to query data in your excel sheets using linq statements.

You could actually use nuget to add LinqToExcel to your MVC solution. Just simply search for "LinqToExcel" and install the package.

After that's done your code would look something like this:

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory();
excel.FileName = "PutFileNameHere";

var details = from x in excel.Worksheet<ExcelDate>() select x;
```

Then you could just loop through the contents of the collection "details" and save that into your database.

```
foreach(var detail in details)
{
    //add logic to save each line to your database
}
```

Here are some helpful links to get you started:

https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/wiki/UsingLinqToExcel

https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of assistance. Would you mind marking this as  an answer? Thanks